# Shader converting nonzero uint to 255

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to implement polygon selection through clicking by first drawing triangle IDs to an off-screen framebuffer and then reading back pixel values at clicked positions via glReadPixels. I am passing ID as unsigned integer to each vertex (and I confirmed that the buffer is correct from apitrace) and outputting it as uvec4 in fragment shader. I set up the framebuffer as RGBA8UI texture (also confirmed units to be correct from apitrace). There is no opengl error and also checked that framebuffer is complete.

The problem is that the output image where the IDs should be always has a value of 255. The area covered by the triangles are modified from the glClear value but they are not (id, 0, 0, 0) but always (255, 0, 0, 0). The exception is those with ID of 0. It seems like somewhere in the shader, the ID is converted to 255 if the ID is not 0. Is this the expected behavior from the code below? Am I doing something wrong?

Vertex buffer:

```
x (float), y (float), z (float), tx (float), ty (float), id (unsigned int)
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Input
layout(location = 0) in vec3 position;
layout(location = 1) in vec2 texCoord;
layout(location = 2) in uint id;

// Output (Varying)
out vec2 v_texCoord;
flat out uint v_id;

// Uniform
uniform mat4 u_model;
uniform mat4 u_view;
uniform mat4 u_projection;

void main()
{
    v_texCoord = texCoord;
    v_id = id;
    gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * u_model * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330 core

// Input (Varying)
in vec2 v_texCoord;
flat in uint v_id;

// Output
layout(location = 0) out uvec4 color;

void main()
{
    color = uvec4(v_id, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

GL_VERSION is 3.3.0 NVIDIA 419.35 and I have updated the driver yesterday.

**-- Edit --**

I was down-voted for lack of information so I created a separate project that just shows my point above with the rest of the code below:

```
#include <glad/glad.h> // Must be included before GLFW header
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

const int WINDOW_WIDTH = 800;
const int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 800;

int main()
{
    // glfw: initialize and configure
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // glfw window creation
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, "LearnOpenGL", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // glad: load all OpenGL function pointers
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress))
    {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;


    // Vertex and fragment shaders
    GLuint shader = glCreateProgram();
    {
        GLint isSuccess = false;
        GLuint vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        GLuint fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

        // Vertex shader
        {
            const GLchar* vertexShaderSource =
                "#version 330 core\n"
                "layout(location = 0) in vec2 position;\n"
                "layout(location = 1) in uint id;\n"
                "flat out uint v_id;\n"
                "void main() {v_id = id; gl_Position = vec4(position.x, position.y, 0.0, 1.0);}\n";
            glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, nullptr);
            glCompileShader(vertexShader);
            glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isSuccess);
            std::cout << "Vertex shader compile status: " << isSuccess << std::endl;
        }

        // Fragment shader
        {
            const GLchar* fragmentShaderSource =
                "#version 330 core\n"
                "layout(location = 0) out uvec4 color;\n"
                "flat in uint v_id;\n"
                "void main() {color = uvec4(v_id, 0, 0, 0);}\n";
            glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, nullptr);
            glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
            glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &isSuccess);
            std::cout << "Fragment shader compile status: " << isSuccess << std::endl;
        }

        glAttachShader(shader, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shader, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shader);
        glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &isSuccess);
        std::cout << "Shader link status: " << isSuccess << std::endl;

        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
    }

    // Vertex Buffer
    GLuint vertexBuffer;
    {
        glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        GLfloat data[] = {
            //  x      y     id
            -1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.0f, -1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
             0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
             1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f
        };
        GLuint* data2 = ((GLuint *)data);
        data2[2] = 0;
        data2[5] = 0;
        data2[8] = 0;
        data2[11] = 1;
        data2[14] = 1;
        data2[17] = 1;
        std::cout << "Size of GLuint: " << sizeof(GLuint) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size of GLfloat: " << sizeof(GLfloat) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Size of vertex buffer: " << sizeof(data) << std::endl;
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(data), data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }

    // Vertex Array
    GLuint vertexArray;
    {
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
        glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
    }

    // Texture for framebuffer
    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    {
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8UI, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGBA_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    }

    // Framebuffer
    GLuint framebuffer;
    {
        GLenum completenessStatus;
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture, 0);
        std::cout << "Framebuffer status: " << (glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) << std::endl;
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    }

    // Clear
    glClearColor(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    GLenum error = glGetError();
    std::cout << "No error: " << (error == GL_NO_ERROR) << std::endl;

    // Draw
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS)
            glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
        {
            glDisable(GL_DITHER);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            glUseProgram(shader);
            glBindVertexArray(vertexArray);
            glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);

            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
            glEnable(GL_DITHER);
        }
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glDeleteProgram(shader);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertexArray);
    glDeleteFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3.3.0 NVIDIA 419.35
Vertex shader compile status: 1
Fragment shader compile status: 1
Shader link status: 1
Size of GLuint: 4
Size of GLfloat: 4
Size of vertex buffer: 72
Framebuffer status: 1
No error: 1
```

Framebuffer is RGBA8UI:

[image: Framebuffer is RGBA8UI]

Vertices are correct:

[image: Vertices are correct]

Triangle with ID of 0 is colored as (0, 0, 0, 0) as expected:

[image: Triangle ID 0]

Area outside triangle is (255, 255, 255, 255) as expected (glClearColor is white):

[image: Outside triangle]

Triangle with ID of 1 is colored as (255, 0, 0, 0). It should be (1, 0, 0, 0):

[image: Triangle ID 1]

The same issue occurs for ID > 1. Why is this the case? How can I make it so that the color is (ID, 0, 0, 0) as shown in the fragment shader?

Comment: How do you specify the array of generic vertex attribute data for the attribute `id`?

Comment: I updated the question by adding the full code. `glVertexAttribPointer(1, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));` is how I specified the ID attribute

Comment: `glVertexAttribPointer` -> `glVertexAttribIPointer` (focus on `I`) - see [`glVertexAttribPointer `](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`glVertexAttribIPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (focus on **`I`**), when defining the array of generic vertex attribute data, for the vertex attribute `in uint id;`.
When vertex attribute data are defined by `glVertexAttribPointer`, then they will be converted to floating point values.

See [OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification; 10.2. CURRENT VERTEX ATTRIBUTE VALUES; page 344](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf)

> The **`VertexAttribI*`** commands specify signed or unsigned fixed-point **values
>   that are stored as signed or unsigned integers**, respectively. Such values are referred to as pure integers.
>
> ...
>
> All other **`VertexAttrib*`** commands specify values that are **converted directly to the internal floating-point representation**.